# Cargo Error: failed to get `X` as a dependency

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am getting this weird error:

```
cargo build
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to get `anyhow` as a dependency of package `FlexDB v0.1.0 (E:\projects\FlexDB)`

Caused by:
  failed to load source for dependency `anyhow`

Caused by:
  Unable to update registry `crates-io`

Caused by:
  failed to fetch `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`

Caused by:
  missing delta bases; class=Indexer (15)
```

My `cargo.toml` file look like this:

```
[package]
name = "FlexDB"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
anyhow = "1"
```

I don't know what to do, I did:

1. `rustup update`
2. Restart computer

Comment: Sounds like you're having internet issues ? You could try cargo clean and cargo build.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@kornel answer did solved this error,

> *"It looks like your ~/.cargo/registry/index directory is corrupted. Delete it and run cargo update again."*

Answer (score 0):

I'm running cargo in docker container so when I got the below error, what I did was I deleted the below directory, below directory path may vary system to system, cargo will print the path along with the error

```
rm  -fr  /usr/local/rust/registry
```